# get set from singleton instance are empty

Tags: c#

I'm currently programming an api, the api is a c ++ plugin what I want to write in C #, the api is actually almost done only I have a problem at the moment which annoys me for hours

the problem is as follows

```
 // this class is in the api dll file
    public class SingleData
    {
        public static Lazy<SingleData> val = new Lazy<SingleData>(() => new IPlugin());
        public static IPlugin Instance { get { return val.Value; } }

        protected SingleData() { }

        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual void plugin_getUser(UserData user) { }
    }    

    // this class is also in the api dll file
    public class DllExport { 
        [DllExport] public static void plugin_getUser(UserData user) { return SingleData.Instance.plugin_getUser(user); }
     }

    // this is NOT in the dll file 
    // I want that people who use my API only make it like this
    public class Main : SingleData {
        public Main() {
           Author = "Hans";
           Name = "test plugin";
        }
        public override void plugin_getUser(UserData user) { 
           Console.WriteLine(user.OnlineTime);
        }    
    }
```

so the problem is now If I remove the singleton I cant use `return SingleData.Instance.plugin_getUser` in the DllExport class and
the `Author` and `Name` variable are empty.

I have some questions now, how can I spend the events in the Main class without having to type `return SingleData.instance.plugin_getUser` in the DllExport class

and the other question is, how could I do it differently, but the main class should be the same as I specified

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a case where you might want to consider the [strangely recurring pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern),

```
    public class SingleData<T> where T : SingleData<T>, new()
    {
        public static Lazy<T> val = new Lazy<T>(() => new T());
        public static IPlugin Instance { get { return val.Value; } }

        protected SingleData() { }

        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual void plugin_getUser(UserData user) { }
    }    

    // this class is also in the api dll file
    public class DllExport
    { 
        [DllExport]
        public static void plugin_getUser(UserData user) { return SingleData<Main>.Instance.plugin_getUser(user); }
     }
```

Usage,

```
    public class Main : SingleData<Main>
    {
        public Main()
        {
           Author = "Hans";
           Name = "test plugin";
        }

        public override void plugin_getUser(UserData user)
        { 
           Console.WriteLine(user.OnlineTime);
        }    
    }
```

Comment: thanxs for your answer, but the only problem is the `Main` is not in the .dll file so I cant use `SingleData<Main>.Instance.plugin_getUser(user)` because Main does not exist

Comment: what about ``plugin_getUser<T>(..) { return SingleData<T> ...`` ?

Comment: erf I see... there seems to be a flaw in the design. You could maybe try to post it as a design question, giving the bigger picture about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-a-simple-plugin-b6174b62 have a look

Comment: plugin_getUser<T> not works, because the type argument T is only in the SingleData I really dont know how I can do it or is there a other way to override it without using return ...